# How to get the same Angular versions for both a local Angular CLI app and a plunk?

Tags: angularjs, angular, plunker, angular-cli

I'm new to both Angular 2.0 and angular-cli.

In order to get myself unstuck, I need to make a plunk with the same version of Angular 2.0 as the one I'm using to make my app, and then post a Stackoverflow question linked to it.

As far as I can tell, I can use versions in the plunk that are listed [here](https://code.angularjs.org/) which currently go up to 2.0.0-beta.17. The Angular-CLI uses 2.0.0-rc.1.

I tried editing this part of my package.json by replacing "2.0.0-rc.1" with "2.0.0-beta.17". That didn't work.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
```

Is it possible to use the cli version (2.0.0-rc.1) in a plunk? I'd rather do that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems that the RC isn't available yet on cdn.
You can try a request on the cdnjs rep. using [this link](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/issues/new?title=%5BRequest%5D%20Add%20_library_name_%20&body=**Library%20name%3A**%20%0A**Git%20repository%20url%3A**%0A**npm%20package%20url(optional)%3A**%20%0A**License(s)%3A**%0A**Official%20homepage%3A**%0A**Wanna%20say%20something?%20Leave%20message%20here%3A**%0A%0A=====================%0ANotes%20from%20cdnjs%20maintainer%3A%0APlease%20read%20the%20README.md%20and%20CONTRIBUTING.md%20document%20first.%0A%0AYou%20are%20welcome%20to%20add%20a%20library%20via%20sending%20pull%20request%2C%0Ait%27ll%20be%20faster%20then%20just%20opening%20a%20request%20issue%2C%0Aand%20please%20don%27t%20forget%20to%20read%20the%20guidelines%20for%20contributing%2C%20thanks!!)

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/bzuAYivIgrsX1tkw0v01?p=preview) by [Mark Rajcok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215945/mark-rajcok) that seems to handle it by getting the code from https://npmcdn.com

```
/**
 * PLUNKER VERSION (based on systemjs.config.js in angular.io)
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 * Override at the last minute with global.filterSystemConfig (as plunkers do)
 */
(function(global) {

  var ngVer = '@2.0.0-rc.1'; // lock in the angular package version; do not let it float to current!

  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var  map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'https://npmcdn.com/angular2-in-memory-web-api' // get latest
  };

  //packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.ts',  defaultExtension: 'ts' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };

  var packageNames = [
      '@angular/common',
      '@angular/compiler',
      '@angular/core',
      '@angular/http',
      '@angular/platform-browser',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
      '@angular/router',
      '@angular/router-deprecated',
      '@angular/upgrade',
  ];

  // add map entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/common@0.0.0-3?main=browser'
  packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    map[pkgName] = 'https://npmcdn.com/' + pkgName + ngVer;
  });

  // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });

  var config = {
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: {
      emitDecoratorMetadata: true
    },
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }

  // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
  if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

  System.config(config);

})(this);


/*
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/
```